# "No such file or directory" from os.mkdir

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

working on a python project, and what it does is it looks at the index of lifehacker.com, then finds all  tags with the class "headline h5 hover-highlight entry-title", then it creates files for each directory. But the only problem is that when i run it, i get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "/home/root/python/The Sony Smartwatch 3: A Runner's Perspective (Updated: 1/5/2015)"`

help would be lovely, thanks!

heres my code atm:

```
import re
import os
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser

url = "http://lifehacker.com/"
url_open = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_open.read())

link = soup.findAll("h1",{"class": "headline h5 hover-highlight entry-title"})
file_directory = "/home/root/python/"

for i in link:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(file_directory, str(i.text)))
    print "Successfully made directory(s)", i.text, "!"
else:
    print "The directory", i.text, "either exists, or there was an error!"
```

Comment: Think about it: You've got `/` characters in your directory name.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sanitize your filename. (Failing to do so is also going to cause you security issues, particularly if you don't prevent things from starting with `../`).

This could be as simple as:

```
safe_name = i.text.replace('/', '_')
os.mkdir(os.path.join(file_directory, safe_name))
```

As it is, your code is trying to create a directory named `2015)`, in a directory named `5`, in a directory named `The Sony Smartwatch 3: A Runner's Perspective (Updated: 1`. Since none of those exist, and `os.mkdir()` isn't recursive, you get the error in question. (If you *want* a recursive operation, see `os.makedirs()` instead).

Comment: im now getting this error:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200b' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @DANIELREAPSOME, that's a different question -- and one that's already been asked and answered here, so you'll have no trouble finding an answer by searching. (`str()` isn't necessarily the right thing for things that aren't pure ASCII).

Comment: Use `os.makedirs()`

Comment: @RahulParashar, a pertinent suggestion *if* the parent directory doesn't exist, but the OP here is appending only a single name. Using `makedirs()` and leaving out the `replace()` doesn't solve your security/sanitization issues (ie. someone intercepting this plain-HTTP connection and injecting a result with the entry title `../.ssh`, for instance, and then simulating a page named `authorized_keys` therein), so it's outright dangerous.